# MongoDB cumulatively append

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

MongoDB cumulatively append

I have:

```
[
    {"d" : 20050511, "u" : 1},
    {"d" : 20050511, "u" : 2},
    {"d" : 20050511, "u" : 3},
    {"d" : 20050511, "u" : 4},

    {"d" : 20050512, "u" : 1},
    {"d" : 20050512, "u" : 2},
    {"d" : 20050512, "u" : 3},
    {"d" : 20050512, "u" : 7},

    {"d" : 20050513, "u" : 18},
    {"d" : 20050513, "u" : 21},
    {"d" : 20050513, "u" : 23}
]
```

I want to convert it to:

```
[
    {"d" : 20050511, "u" : 1},
    {"d" : 20050511, "u" : 2},
    {"d" : 20050511, "u" : 3},
    {"d" : 20050511, "u" : 4},

    {"d" : 20050512, "u" : 1},
    {"d" : 20050512, "u" : 2},
    {"d" : 20050512, "u" : 3},
    {"d" : 20050512, "u" : 7}
    {"d" : 20050512, "u" : 4},

    {"d" : 20050513, "u" : 18},
    {"d" : 20050513, "u" : 21},
    {"d" : 20050513, "u" : 23},
    {"d" : 20050513, "u" : 1},
    {"d" : 20050513, "u" : 2},
    {"d" : 20050513, "u" : 3},
    {"d" : 20050513, "u" : 4},
    {"d" : 20050513, "u" : 7}
]
```

Basically, I want to cumulatively move forward for each date (I am storing dates as ints); meaning for 20050512 it is distinct union of 20050511 + 20050512; for 20050513 it is distinct union of 20050512 + 20050513

I tried some aggregation pipe lining, but with little success. I can do this in application layer but that will cause huge i/o and long time; since the data is for over 15 years and each date there are over 50K docs.

Comment: You want to update an array field or you want to get a result of a query ?

Comment: I don't want to update an array field; the above is my document structure; the square brackets are misleading; my apologies.

Comment: So, Do you want to insert some new documents in your current collection ?

Comment: Yes. I want to update the collection; the value for field "u" for field "d" will be a union of previous "d"; a cumulative increase